# Drupal 7 date_popup form element wrong value submitted

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-fapi

I"m rendering following date picker element in a custom form using Drupal 7:

```
    $form['navigation']['calendar_popup'] = array(
        '#type' => 'date_popup',
        '#title' => t('Date', [], $t_context),
        '#title_display' => 'invisible',
        '#default_value' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s', time()),
        '#date_format' => 'd-m-Y',
        '#size' => 10,
        '#date_label_position' => 'none', // none within
        '#date_increment' => 15,
        '#date_year_range' => '2008:+1',
        '#description' => '',
        '#required' => false,      
    );
```

It is November 10th today and the displayed element text is 10-11-2019. 
But when the form is submitted on a handheld device (I use Samsung Galaxy S5 emulation with my Chrome desktop browser), the field text briefly changes to '11-10-2019' and actually '2019-10-11' gets submitted. Same on a physical Galaxy A series handheld).

Desktop browsers don't have this issue.

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
 $form['navigation']['calendar_popup'] = array(
    '#type' => 'date_popup',
    '#title' => t('Date', [], $t_context),
    '#title_display' => 'invisible',
    '#default_value' => date('Y-m-d', time()), // change format passed
    '#date_format' => 'd-m-Y',
    '#size' => 10,
    '#date_label_position' => 'none', // none within
    '#date_increment' => 15,

    '#date_timezone'       => date_default_timezone(), // add this

    '#date_year_range' => '2008:+1',
    '#description' => '',
    '#required' => false,      
);
```

=> force timezone + change date default value format

Comment: Unfortunately no luck. the field renders today (November 12th) with text  12/11/2019 in it. But $form_state['values']['calendar_popup'] submitted value is still '2019-12-11' when using Chrome on my Samsung Galaxy. Desktop Chrome running under Win10 is OK. I suspect something is wrong with the JQuery timepicker plugin shipped with the Date Popup module. Will give wvega a try.

Comment: You can try to use https://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.date-default-timezone-set.php  to force yourbackend to use right UTC

Comment: @PavelMurnikov did you try ?

Comment: Yes I did try you form element suggestion. Now it's working. Later I make some additional updates, which still need to figure out. Will post answer to my question accordingly.